# Pasar una variable al controlador desde AJAX en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo el siguiente problema, en una vista obtengo los datos de un usuario a través de un `foreach` y uno de ellos es el código, el cual mediante un enlace, ejecuto una función que le paso como parámetro el mismo código:

```php
<a  href="" onclick="cargarID(<?=$fila->Id_usuario?>)"><?=$fila->Id_usuario?></a></td>
```

La función envía el id a un método de mi controlador:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cargarID(id= null){
        if(id) {
            $.ajax({
                  url:"http://localhost/sistema/usuario_consulta/getID/"+id,
                  type:"POST",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success:function(respuesta){
                      window.location.href = "http://localhost/sistema/usuario_consulta/index";
                  }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Éste es mi controlador, hago esto porque necesito enviarle un parámetro a una consulta que tengo en el modelo.

```php
function index()
{
    $this->load->view('guest/section');
    $datos['arrPerfil'] = $this->model_usuario->consulta();
    $this->load->view('user/usuario_view', $datos);
}

public function getID($id) 
{
    if($id) {
        $data = $this->model_usuario->consulta($id);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

en el modelo tengo el siguiente código:

```php
function consulta($id){

    $query = $this->db-> query("select Id_usuario, nombre, telefono from usuario where Id_usuario ='".$id."'");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
     }
   }
```

donde necesito de ese parámetro para enjecutar la consulta y después devolverla en un array en el index del controlador

```php
function index()
{

    $datos['arrPerfil'] = $this->model_usuario->consulta();
    $this->load->view('user/usuario_view', $datos);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que la siguiente linea funciona:

```
<a  href="" onclick="cargarID(<?=$fila->Id_usuario?>)"><?=$fila->Id_usuario?></a>
```

Y esta llegando correctamente el Id_usuario.

Tu función

```
function cargarID(id= null){
      if(id) {
      $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/sistema/usuario_consulta/getID/"+id,
      type:"POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(respuesta){
         window.location.href = "http://localhost/sistema/usuario_consulta/index";
       }
     });
    }
   }
```

Está mal en la parte de la llamada ajax, específicamente en:

```
type:"POST",
```

Estas enviando una petición `post` y en tu controlador en CodeIgniter lo que esperas es una petición `get`

```
public function getID($id) 
{
  if($id) {
    $data = $this->model_usuario->consulta($id);
    echo json_encode($data);
  }
}
```

No se que devuelve tu consulta en `model_usario` pero ahí deberías devolver un arreglo que después puedas recorrer con jquery o javascript.

Lo que podrías hacer es cambiar el tipo de petición en la llamada ajax de `POST` a `GET`, o mejor te recomendaría que lo hagas mediante `POST` y también cambies tu controlador en codeigniter, para que tengas mayor control de los datos que envías.

Por ejemplo tu llamada ajax quedaría:

```
function cargarID(id){
   if(id != null) {
         $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost/sistema/usuario_consulta/getID",
            type:"POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'id_persona': id},
            success:function(respuesta){
             window.location.href = "http://localhost/sistema/usuario_consulta/index";
           }
         });
   }
}
```

Y tu función `getID` en el controlador quedaría:

```
public function getID() 
{
  $id = $this->input->post("id_persona");
  if($id != null) {
    $data = $this->model_usuario->consulta($id);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

No comprendo que quieres hacer, para que usas ajax si no vas a usar ese id en esa llamada, el problema que tienes es que no te llega el id a la función index de tu controlador, si solo quieres eso podrías hacerlo directamente en tu link.

por ejemplo

```
<a  href="<?php echo site_url()."/usuario_consulta/index/". $fila->Id_usuario;?>"> <?=$fila->Id_usuario?> </a>
```

Luego tu función index quedaria asi:

```
function index($id){

    $datos['arrPerfil'] = $this->model_usuario->consulta($id);
    $this->load->view('user/usuario_view', $datos);
}
```

Comment: hola juan gracias por responder, e cambiado el las partes que as mencionado y sigo teniendo el error. voy a subir el codigo que tengo en el modelo para que se entienda mejor

Comment: @Criss acabo de hacer un edit.

Comment: muchas gracias @juan, estado abordando mal mi problema, con tu ayuda lo resolvi, una pregunta mas es posible pasarle mas de un arreglo ala vista, en caso de que qiera realizar otra consulta mas?

Comment: De nada, si te sirvió la respuesta considera marcarla como solución a tu problema, de esta manera mejoran las estadisticas del sitio y otros usuarios pueden encontrar util tu pregunta. Respondiendo a tu inquietud, si si puedes enviar mas datos por la URL si a eso te refieres, despues del nombre de la funcion vienen los parametros, por ejemplo http://localhost/sistema/controlador/funcion/parametro1/parametro2 en es caso la funcion en tu controlador deberia tener 2 variables como parametros ejemplo: function funcion($param1, $param2){}